# How to control ubuntu laptop from windows PC

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, windows-10

I am a developer working on the Ubuntu laptop, I have been searching for a way to work on my laptop from my windows PC as my PC has a bigger monitor I tried screen sharing with applications but it is sloppy. Is there any way I can achieve this with an efficient solution?

My laptop has a HDMI port.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: From the description, it seems you want to use the monitor of the Windows PC as an extended monitor for the Ubuntu laptop. If your monitor also has HDMI port, you can hook it up to the laptop's HDMI, then setup a "join" or "mirror" in the Ubuntu display settings. If the monitor has VGA but no HDMI, then you can do the same thing by using a HDMI to VGA converter in between the laptop's HDMI port and monitor's VGA port. I am not putting this as an answer because your question needs modification if your need was indeed what I propose.

Answer (score 0):

1.Installing xrdp (x remote desktop protocol) and set firewall rule for traffic.

```sh
sudo apt install xrdp
sudo systemctl enable --now xrdp
# best use least privilege and I am assuming both PCs share a local network
sudo ufw allow from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 port 3389 proto tcp
```

2.Make sure that you are not logged in.

3.Use the RDP client installed in Windows PC to log in.

You might need to repeat steps 2+3 several times.